# Docker & Wordpress - The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/.../

Tags: wordpress, docker

**Error**:

The uploaded file could not be moved to `wp-content/uploads/.../...`.

**Environment**:

Wordpress Docker image is created from a base Wordpress image then the files are mapped in and out, for development:

```
version: '3'

services:
  wordpress:
    restart: always
    environment:
      WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: ...
      WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: ...
      WORDPRESS_DB_USER: ...
      WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: ...

    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
      - 38991:80
    volumes:
      - ./:/var/www/html
```

We talk to a dev database hosted external to the Docker container.

Image is built - and sent up to the server. Then, CMS user attempts to upload an image and the Wordpress build moans that the uploaded file could not be moved to `wp-content/uploads/.../...`. We don't get this error on `localhost`.

Could some devops experts kindly point us in the right direction on what needs to be done for this to tally up on the server.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The permissions are incorrect on the `wp-content/uploads` directory. I had the same error and in my case the upload folder's permissions and user/group where set wrong and also some folders inside were set to root. But that's probably because I imported a backup.

To fix the upload you can add the following two commands to your deploy pipeline/script or use `docker exec -it <container-name> bash` to perform it manually on the container.

1. Set the correct user/group on the uploads folder: `$ chown -R www-data:www-data uploads/*`
2. Set the correct permissions: `$ chmod 755 uploads/*`

Comment: Should be chown -R www-data:www-data uploads/